# sqlException occured during data insertion using WFA interface

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

I'm using Windows application form interface from Visual Studio and MSSMS doing a demo to insert data into "crystaldb" local database for creating crystal reports. I checked and assumed I have the correct Table in my sql database I am referencing and it's called "crystaldb" for sure. I did inserted 1 row data successfully for the first time compiling but after that there was sql exception thrown when compiled.

> Here's the interface:

[image: Interface for data insertion]

> Here's the code for the "Submit" and "Close" buttons and main function:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZPCU0209\\SQLSERVERYANG;Initial Catalog=crystaldb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into cystaldb values('"+ textBox1.Text +"',"+ textBox2.Text +",'"+ textBox3.Text +"','"+ textBox4.Text +"','"+ textBox5.Text +"','"+ textBox6.Text +"','"+ textBox7.Text +"','"+ textBox8.Text +"','"+ textBox9.Text +"','"+ textBox10.Text +"',"+ textBox11.Text +");",con);
        int o= sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(o + " : Record has been inserted");
        con.Close();
    }
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

> This is the database table setting:

[image]

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Invalid object name 'cystaldb'.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What is the error code and error text for the SqlException?  SqlException is a very generic error.  Without more information there is no way to be sure what the cause of the error is.

Comment: The sqlexception additional info is:  Invalid object name 'cystaldb'.

Comment: Is crystaldb the table name or the database name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled crystaldb in your query:

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into **cystaldb** values(...));
```

You are missing the 'r' in crystaldb.

Comment: Oh Jesus! OMG I should've noticed that before posting this question. I need to apologize to all.

Comment: Sometimes I overthink and dismiss the basics and spelling. Should've be aware of minute details in programming. Just started my career. Good luck to you!

Comment: Hey, don't feel too bad, I noticed it only just before I posted about it.

Comment: Hey, another extend question, how to check out this without warning error in Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you asking how to catch typos before they cause an error while running?

Comment: Yes, that's the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136986/discussion-between-brandon-kramer-and-rapsoulcecil).

Answer (score 1):

you missed some single quotes, here try now.

```
 SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into cystaldb values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ textBox3.Text +"','"+ textBox4.Text +"','"+ textBox5.Text +"','"+ textBox6.Text +"','"+ textBox7.Text +"','"+ textBox8.Text +"','"+ textBox9.Text +"','"+ textBox10.Text +"','"+ textBox11.Text +"')",con);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to empty the cookies and refresh the local database. I replaced this quote but still got the same sqlException: Invalid object name 'cystaldb'. @Baloch